# Convergence of the expected value of bounded random variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of bounded random variable such that 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]\to\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]
$$
with $X$ a bounded random variable.  Can I conclude that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\,W\right]\to\mathbb{E}\left[X\,W\right]
$$

for any bounded random variable $W$ ?

Comment: @nicomezi in my counterexample we even have $X_n\stackrel{d}{=}X$ for every $n$.

Comment: I meant $X_n \overset{P} \to X$ indeed, made a confusion. @drhab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Throw a fair coin and for every $n$ let $X_n=1$ if it lands on heads and $X_n=0$ otherwise.

Let $X=1$ if it lands on tails and $X=0$ otherwise.

Then let $W=X$ so that $X_nW=0$ and $XW=X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ have uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$, $X_n=-X$ for all $n$ and $W=X$. Then  $EX_n W=-1/3$ for all $n$ and $EXW=1/3$ even though $EX_n =0 \to 0=EX$.